# Build text path using "pic" from library "angles"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to do a polygon as bellow. But I am put the angle title manually as you can see in my code. Do you have any idea to do this in a smart manner?

[image: output]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,calc,plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\escala}{.02} % escala
\tikzset{MeuAngulo/.style={draw=blue,<-,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=25pt,semithick}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=\escala,yscale=\escala]
%The points
\coordinate (A) at (294,254);
\coordinate (B) at (120,351);
\coordinate (C) at (0,180);
\coordinate (D) at (89,0);
\coordinate (E) at (240,100);

%The polygon
\draw[thick] (A) node[above] {A} -- 
             (B) node[above] {B} -- 
             (C) node[left] {C} -- 
             (D) node[below] {D} -- 
             (E) node[right] {E} --
             (A) 
pic["",MeuAngulo,angle eccentricity=1.8] {angle=B--A--E}    
pic["",MeuAngulo,angle eccentricity=1.4] {angle=C--B--A}
pic["",MeuAngulo,angle eccentricity=1.9] {angle=D--C--B}
pic["",MeuAngulo,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=E--D--C} 
pic["",MeuAngulo,angle eccentricity=1.8] {angle=A--E--D}
;    

% The problem is here. I appreciate if you do this easily, some think like:
% pic["",MeuAngulo,angle eccentricity=1.8] {angle=A--E--D} \path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text= $99{^\circ}48'54''$~}}]

\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, 
text= $99{^\circ}48'54''$~}}] (275,210) arc [start angle=250.68, end angle=150.86, radius=48];

\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, 
text= $95{^\circ}55'15''$~}}] (160,325) arc [start angle=330.86, end angle=234.94, radius=48];

\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, 
text= $118{^\circ}37'50''$~}}] (43,140) arc [start angle=-60, end angle=100, radius=48];

\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, 
text= $82{^\circ}47'42''$~}}] (70,50) arc [start angle=150, end angle=40, radius=48];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way of simplifying things. `deco angle` is a `pic` based on `angle` which takes two arguments. The second is the angle to be specified as a decoration for the path. As the following shows, you can continue to use `angle` in the normal way.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,calc,plotmarks,decorations.text}

\newcommand{\escala}{.02} % escala
\tikzset{MeuAngulo/.style={draw=blue,<-,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=25pt,semithick}}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  pics/deco angle/.style n args = 2{
    setup code  = \tikz@lib@angle@parse#1\pgf@stop,
    background code = \tikz@lib@angle@background#1\pgf@stop,
    foreground code = \tikz@lib@decoangle@foreground#1{#2}\pgf@stop,
  },
  pics/angle/.default=A--B--C,
  angle eccentricity/.initial=.6,
  angle radius/.initial=5mm
}

\def\tikz@lib@decoangle@foreground#1--#2--#3#4\pgf@stop{%
  \path [name prefix ..] [pic actions, fill=none, shade=none]
  ([shift={(\tikz@start@angle@temp:\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt)}]#2.center)
    arc [start angle=\tikz@start@angle@temp, end
    angle=\tikz@end@angle@temp, radius=\tikz@lib@angle@rad pt];
  \path [name prefix ..] [fill=none, shade=none, decorate, decoration={text along path, text={$|\scriptstyle|~#4~||$}}]
  ([shift={(\tikz@end@angle@temp:\tikz@lib@angle@rad+2 pt)}]#2.center)
    arc [start angle=\tikz@end@angle@temp, end angle=\tikz@start@angle@temp, radius=\tikz@lib@angle@rad+2 pt];
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=\escala,yscale=\escala]
    %The points
    \coordinate (A) at (294,254);
    \coordinate (B) at (120,351);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,180);
    \coordinate (D) at (89,0);
    \coordinate (E) at (240,100);

    %The polygon
    \draw[thick] (A) node[above] {A} --
      (B) node[above] {B} --
      (C) node[left] {C} --
      (D) node[below] {D} --
      (E) node[right] {E} --
      (A)
      pic["", MeuAngulo, angle eccentricity=1.8] {deco angle={B--A--E}{99{^\circ}48'54''}}
      pic["", MeuAngulo, angle eccentricity=1.4] {deco angle={C--B--A}{95{^\circ}55'15''}}
      pic["", MeuAngulo, angle eccentricity=1.9] {deco angle={D--C--B}{118{^\circ}37'50''}}
      pic["", MeuAngulo, angle eccentricity=1.3] {deco angle={E--D--C}{82{^\circ}47'42''}}
      pic["", MeuAngulo, angle eccentricity=1.8] {angle=A--E--D}
      ;

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: deco angles]

Comment: Thank you very much. I would never be able to do that alone. I am trying to understand your code with the aim to do it able to change the direction of the title. For example, at B the angle is upside down. I am thinking in create other "decoangle" macro, changing the start and the and point of the path.

Comment: @Alexandre Yes, that should work. You can switch the `start` and `end` in the specification of the angles. I actually did this to get the text to follow the direction of the angle. If you instead you the original `\path` (the first one in `\tikz@lib@decoangle@foreground`), the text will go the other way. However, you will need to tweak the alignment, I think, to get the text on the outside, rather than the inside, of the angle. Does that make sense?

Comment: I did the "adaptation", that is, a other macro, and it is working. It is not elegant, because I double your code and mine code has only few modifications of yours. Thanks again.

Comment: @Alexandre My code only has a few modifications when compared with the original source I adapted from the angle library ;).

Comment: This is beautiful polygon, but  too complicated for me  to understand. I have been playing with it for hours. All I want I want is  angles in degrees, no minutes and seconds, and the angles in the arcs. Can this be done easily, or not?

Comment: @Jon If you don't specify minutes and seconds, they won't appear, so I'm not sure what the issue is? But you don't need my answer at all if you just want the angle inside the arc. Just use the `angles` library. The whole point of this answer is to position the text differently. If you want the default, my answer just introduces useless complexity.

Comment: Cfr thank you for your quick reply much appreciated, but I wanted something simple like below. Is there a way of doing it quicker, i.e. with less code.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[draw ] (0,0) node[left] (6) {6}
        -- (1.5,-1) node[below] (5) {5}
        -- (3.5, -0.8) node[below] (4) {4}
        -- (6,0.75) node[right] (3) {3}
        -- (3.5, 2) node[above] (2) {2}
        -- (1,2) node[above] (1) {1}
        -- cycle;
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);   % 6
\coordinate (b) at (1.5,-1);  % 5
\coordinate (c) at (3.5,-0.8); % 4      
\coordinate (d) at (6,0.75);    %3
\coordinate (e) at (3.5, 2);  %2
\coordinate (f) at (1,2);   % 1


%1
\draw pic[draw,fill=green!30,angle radius=0.4cm,"$  30 ^ \circ
$" shift={(2mm,-5mm)}] {angle= a--f--e};

%6      
\draw pic[draw,fill=green!30,angle radius=0.4cm,"$ 60 ^ \circ$" shift={(4mm,2mm)}] {angle= b--a--f};


%5
\draw pic[draw,fill=green!30,angle radius=0.4cm,"$\beta$" shift={(0mm,4mm)}] {angle= c--b--a};

%4      
\draw pic[draw,fill=green!30,angle radius=0.4cm,"$\alpha$" shift={(0mm,4mm)}] {angle= d--c--b};

%3
\draw pic[draw,fill=green!30,angle radius=0.4cm,"$\gamma$" shift={(-5mm,0mm)}] {angle= e--d--c};

%2
\draw pic[draw,fill=green!30,angle radius=0.4cm,"$\gamma$" shift={(0mm,-5mm)}] {angle= f--e--d};
        
        
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Fine. Can you please add some explanation to your question? Thank you

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If you want to ask a new question, please do so and link to this one if relevant. If you're the same Jon commenting on my answer above, I don't understand your question as it stands. I'm not sure what output you're looking for (e.g. where the labels should be) or what code you want to reduce. Maybe you just need to define a `style` so you can reuse the common bits of your customisation?